# How can I see the list of people who have been invited to like a page on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-like

I administer a Facebook page with two other people. All three have invited a bunch of different people. How can I see the list of all people who have been invited by us three to like the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now there is no way to see the list of people who have been invited to like a page. But you can see the list of your friends whom you have invited and who have liked the page.

Go to your page, hover over the cursor on **...More** tab, from the drop down menu, click on **Invite Friends**. A window will popup which show you all your friends who have liked the page, who have been invited to like the page and whom you can invite.

On the popup window if you choose the option *Selected*, it will list all the friends who have been invited but not liked the page.

You cannot re-invite your friends until they cancel the current ones.